# List foreign keys dependencies that refer to a given table

Tags: postgresql, information-schema

RDBMS: PostgreSQL 9.6

I desire to list the foreign keys for a given table and schema. I am about 90 % there but I also desire to know what options were used to make the fkey. Example `on delete restrict` or `on delete update`

```
create or replace function it.table_foreign_keys_getlist(_schema text
                                                       , _table text) 
                           returns TABLE(primary_key_ns text
                                       , primary_key_table text
                                       , foreign_key_ns text
                                       , foreign_key_table text
                                        )
     language sql
 as $$
 SELECT
     n1.nspname::TEXT  AS primary_key_ns,
     c1.relname::TEXT  AS primary_key_table,
     n2.nspname::TEXT  AS foreign_key_ns,
     c2.relname::TEXT  AS foreign_key_table
 FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint c
 JOIN ONLY pg_catalog.pg_class c1     ON c1.oid = c.confrelid
 JOIN ONLY pg_catalog.pg_class c2     ON c2.oid = c.conrelid
 JOIN ONLY pg_catalog.pg_namespace n1 ON n1.oid = c1.relnamespace
 JOIN ONLY pg_catalog.pg_namespace n2 ON n2.oid = c2.relnamespace
 WHERE c1.relkind = 'r'
   AND c.contype  = 'f'
   AND CASE WHEN _schema = '' THEN TRUE ELSE n1.nspname = _schema END
   AND CASE WHEN _table  = '' THEN TRUE ELSE c1.relname = _table  END
 ORDER BY 1,2,3,4;
 $$;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the columns `confupdtype` and `confdeltype` in the catalog [`pg_constraint`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-constraint.html).

The codes mean:

> Foreign key deletion action code: `a` = no action, `r` = restrict, `c` = cascade, `n` = set null, `d` = set default